# Visual Studio 2013 Crashing on Open: system.invalidoperationexception attempting to activate an adapter in state TextViewInitializing

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2013

My VS2013 is crashing whenever I open any project. This seemed to happen after switching to aspx web view while working on a webpage. There error is:

"System.InvalidOperationException attempting to activate an adapter in state TextViewInitializing"

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ojGH.png) is a screenshot and the activity log. Any ideas anyone?

Activity Log

```
Activity Monitor Log 
infos 109 
warnings 0 
errors 1 

#   Type    Description     GUID    Hr  Source      Time (UTC)

1  Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 version: 12.0.21005.1   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.060 
2  Running in User Groups: Administrators Users   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.060 
3  Available Drive Space: C:\ drive has 237998149632 bytes; D:\ drive has 1535590400 bytes; E:\ drive has 50925568 bytes; M:\ drive has 989560467456 bytes   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.061 
4  Internet Explorer Version: 11.0.9600.18283   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.061 
5  .NET Framework Version: 4.0.40305.0   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.061 
6  MSXML Version: 6.30.7601.18980   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.061 
7  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.110 
8  Begin package load [Task Scheduler Package] {00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.110 
9  Initialized ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider from SetSite.   Package Framework 2016/04/18 20:37:57.114 
10  End package load [Task Scheduler Package] {00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:57.115 
493  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.823 
494  Begin package load [Visual Studio Help Package] {4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.823 
495  Loading UI library
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\IDE\*\msenvui.dll {4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.823 
496  End package load [Visual Studio Help Package] {4A791146-19E4-11D3-B86B-00C04F79F802}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.823 
497  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {D4F5086C-54B9-4B07-BD22-AF72D5B9228F}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.823 
498  Begin package load [Telerik.CommonPackage.Telerik_CommonPackagePackage, Telerik.CommonPackage, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d63abc9583eb6f32] {D4F5086C-54B9-4B07-BD22-AF72D5B9228F}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.823 
499  End package load [Telerik.CommonPackage.Telerik_CommonPackagePackage, Telerik.CommonPackage, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d63abc9583eb6f32] {D4F5086C-54B9-4B07-BD22-AF72D5B9228F}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.825 
500  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {94C35263-71D0-4F81-886E-C1E23EA9C837}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.825 
501  Begin package load [Telerik.VSX.UserSettingsPackage.UserSettingsPackage, Telerik.VSX.UserSettingsPackage.2016.1.111.0, Version=2016.1.111.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0dfdc51bd06071b4] {94C35263-71D0-4F81-886E-C1E23EA9C837}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.825 
502  End package load [Telerik.VSX.UserSettingsPackage.UserSettingsPackage, Telerik.VSX.UserSettingsPackage.2016.1.111.0, Version=2016.1.111.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0dfdc51bd06071b4] {94C35263-71D0-4F81-886E-C1E23EA9C837}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.830 
503  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {057D8865-D4BB-46E8-B71E-E24FED08F4B9}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.830 
504  Begin package load [Telerik.Web.UI.VSPackage.VSPackage, Telerik.Web.UI.VSPackage.2016.1.111.0, Version=2016.1.111.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0dfdc51bd06071b4] {057D8865-D4BB-46E8-B71E-E24FED08F4B9}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.830 
505  End package load [Telerik.Web.UI.VSPackage.VSPackage, Telerik.Web.UI.VSPackage.2016.1.111.0, Version=2016.1.111.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0dfdc51bd06071b4] {057D8865-D4BB-46E8-B71E-E24FED08F4B9}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.843 
506  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {CF6A5C16-83B0-4D04-B702-195C35C6E887}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.870 
507  Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage] {CF6A5C16-83B0-4D04-B702-195C35C6E887}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.870 
508  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
509  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
510  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
511  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
512  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
513  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
514  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
515  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
516  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
517  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
518  End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage] {CF6A5C16-83B0-4D04-B702-195C35C6E887}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.871 
519  Loading .NET AddIn: GitPlugin.Connect   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.897 
520  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.898 
521  Begin package load [Visual Studio Environment Menu Package] {715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.898 
522  End package load [Visual Studio Environment Menu Package] {715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.898 
523  Calling OnConnection for Addin: GitPlugin.Connect   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:58.917 
524  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.200 
525  Begin package load [Visual Studio Debugger] {C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.204 
526  Loading UI library
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\Packages\Debugger\*\VSDebugUI.dll {C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.204 
527  End package load [Visual Studio Debugger] {C9DD4A57-47FB-11D2-83E7-00C04F9902C1}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.242 
528  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.283 
529  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.283 
530  ProductID:    VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.550 
531  Microsoft Data Access Version: 6.1.7601.17514   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.550 
532  Application Name: Microsoft Visual Studio   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.550 
533  SKU Edition: Professional   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.550 
534  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.550 
535  Begin package load [Global Search Package] {18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.550 
536  End package load [Global Search Package] {18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.551 
537  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.562 
538  Begin package load [Visual Studio Common IDE Package] {6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.562 
539  End package load [Visual Studio Common IDE Package] {6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.564 
540  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {588205E0-66E0-11D3-8600-00C04F6123B3}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.594 
541  Begin package load [Visual Studio Component Enumerator Package] {588205E0-66E0-11D3-8600-00C04F6123B3}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.595 
542  Loading UI library
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\*\compsvcspkgui.dll {588205E0-66E0-11D3-8600-00C04F6123B3}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.595 
543  End package load [Visual Studio Component Enumerator Package] {588205E0-66E0-11D3-8600-00C04F6123B3}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.595 
544  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {B718A162-0361-4B0E-920B-D88D70BE609B}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.595 
545  Begin package load [Visual Studio Build Manager Package] {B718A162-0361-4B0E-920B-D88D70BE609B}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.595 
546  End package load [Visual Studio Build Manager Package] {B718A162-0361-4B0E-920B-D88D70BE609B}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.599 
547  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {4825B9A3-93E2-4327-9044-41F72EE7E5C9}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.604 
548  Begin package load [File Change Manager Package] {4825B9A3-93E2-4327-9044-41F72EE7E5C9}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.604 
549  End package load [File Change Manager Package] {4825B9A3-93E2-4327-9044-41F72EE7E5C9}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.604 
550  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {2C0F61BF-3C36-468C-94B8-4021965749E7}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.607 
551  Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.VisualStudioPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35] {2C0F61BF-3C36-468C-94B8-4021965749E7}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.607 
552  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.611 
553  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.611 
554  End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.VisualStudioPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35] {2C0F61BF-3C36-468C-94B8-4021965749E7}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.612 
555  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {98BF0691-D23C-4897-A241-9CF5BEFDCC4A}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.612 
556  Begin package load [NuGetVSEventsPackage] {98BF0691-D23C-4897-A241-9CF5BEFDCC4A}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.612 
557  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.619 
558  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.619 
559  End package load [NuGetVSEventsPackage] {98BF0691-D23C-4897-A241-9CF5BEFDCC4A}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.620 
560  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {F97FC405-54EB-4873-9215-24B7CFA8A75D}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.633 
561  Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson.JsonPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson] {F97FC405-54EB-4873-9215-24B7CFA8A75D}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.633 
562  End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson.JsonPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson] {F97FC405-54EB-4873-9215-24B7CFA8A75D}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.636 
563  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {D209E4D9-0F58-4BC3-A529-FDCF20967DC0}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.636 
564  Begin package load [IntegrationPackage] {D209E4D9-0F58-4BC3-A529-FDCF20967DC0}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.636 
565  Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.976 
566  Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:37:59.976 
567  End package load [IntegrationPackage] {D209E4D9-0F58-4BC3-A529-FDCF20967DC0}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.045 
568  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {A27A14C1-CF18-41F2-A456-78ED84878147}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.045 
569  Begin package load [FormsIntellisensePackage] {A27A14C1-CF18-41F2-A456-78ED84878147}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.045 
570  End package load [FormsIntellisensePackage] {A27A14C1-CF18-41F2-A456-78ED84878147}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.141 
571  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {79EA5554-6FFB-4AE3-86E1-F8174A84262A}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.141 
572  Begin package load [UnifiedMigrationPackage] {79EA5554-6FFB-4AE3-86E1-F8174A84262A}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.141 
573  End package load [UnifiedMigrationPackage] {79EA5554-6FFB-4AE3-86E1-F8174A84262A}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.174 
574  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.205 
575  Begin package load [ProviderPackage] {5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.205 
576  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {1491E936-6FFE-474E-8371-30E5920D8FDD}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.221 
577  Begin package load [Image Service Package] {1491E936-6FFE-474E-8371-30E5920D8FDD}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.221 
578  End package load [Image Service Package] {1491E936-6FFE-474E-8371-30E5920D8FDD}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.221 
579  End package load [ProviderPackage] {5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.261 
580  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {BEB01DDF-9D2B-435B-A9E7-76557E2B6B52}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.278 
581  Begin package load [VsDebugPresentationPackage,version=12.0.0.0,publicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,culture=neutral] {BEB01DDF-9D2B-435B-A9E7-76557E2B6B52}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.278 
582  End package load [VsDebugPresentationPackage,version=12.0.0.0,publicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,culture=neutral] {BEB01DDF-9D2B-435B-A9E7-76557E2B6B52}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.297 
583  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {AC2D3F3C-563E-4308-BC26-E00D49746A74}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.362 
584  Begin package load [Microsoft Visual Studio Designer Bootstrap Package] {AC2D3F3C-563E-4308-BC26-E00D49746A74}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.362 
585  End package load [Microsoft Visual Studio Designer Bootstrap Package] {AC2D3F3C-563E-4308-BC26-E00D49746A74}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.366 
586  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {9B3B4731-2399-4055-8CE3-408494927371}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.367 
587  Begin package load [CommandsPackage] {9B3B4731-2399-4055-8CE3-408494927371}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.367 
588  End package load [CommandsPackage] {9B3B4731-2399-4055-8CE3-408494927371}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.369 
589  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {7A4E8D96-5D5B-4415-9FAB-D6DCC56F47FB}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.369 
590  Begin package load [Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage.BootstrapPackage, Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage, version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] {7A4E8D96-5D5B-4415-9FAB-D6DCC56F47FB}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.369 
591  End package load [Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage.BootstrapPackage, Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage, version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] {7A4E8D96-5D5B-4415-9FAB-D6DCC56F47FB}  VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.374 
592 ERROR Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{be4d7042-ba3f-11d2-840e-00c04f9902c1} Frame caption: Breakpoints Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: Attempting to activate an adapter in state TextViewInitializing at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.Init_OnActivation() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.ShimHostNowVisible(Object sender, EventArgs e) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.TextViewShimHost.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent() at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout() at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize() at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.HwndToolbarHost.OnToolbarTrayCreated(VsToolWindowToolBarTray newTray, VSTWT_LOCATION trayLocation) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.BaseToolbarHost.AddToolbar(UInt64 id, VSTWT_LOCATION location, IDropTarget dropTarget, IOleCommandTarget commandTarget, Boolean copyToolbarData) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.BaseToolbarHost.AddToolbar(VSTWT_LOCATION location, Guid& toolbarGuid, UInt32 toolbarId) at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()   VisualStudio 2016/04/18 20:38:00.686
```

Comment: Hi did you get anywhere with this?  I am getting same issue

Comment: Have you Googled your error? This is the Microsoft post that comes up: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/535eff23-fb40-40a6-960b-29c91e9145dc/visual-studio-has-encountered-an-exception-this-may-be-caused-by-an-extension?forum=vsdebug

Comment: Hi Alan Macdonald. Yes I did resolve the issue. The problem arose from my computer accidentally being powered off while I was working on my project. I accidentally switched off my power strip and everything cut off while I was working.

Comment: I think I either cleared all the temp files or I reinstalled visual studios 2013. I'll look for the instructions to clear the temp files and repost them when I find them.

Comment: I started getting this error when I installed InstallShield LE on VS2013. Once I removed InstallShield LE problem got solved.